# Is there a continuation to Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children?

Tags: final-fantasy

*Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children* is a 3D anime movie I watched more than some years ago and it's been a long time I've been searching for it's continuation story.

Is there such a continuation to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Final Fantasy VII, as you probably already know, originally started as a game. There have been several installments as either games or animes. With regards to story in chronological order, there is a game set a year after the events in Advent Children. It's called [Final Fantasy VII - Dirge of Cerberus](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Dirge_of_Cerberus_-Final_Fantasy_VII-). [Vincent Valentine](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Vincent_Valentine) is the main protagonist in this game. The story is indeed connected overall to the series, but it isn't exactly that much relevant to Advent Children.

Comment: is there a movie before the advent children instead

Comment: @bzal there's a Crisis Core anime but this would pale in comparison to the PSP game of the same name. both star Zack during the period before Sephiroth went insane and also shows you the fates of Zack and Cloud before the start of VII. there is also the On the Way to a Smile mini series set after VII but before Advent Children though i havn't seen it myself

Comment: @Memor-X, what is the title of the mini series?

Comment: @bzal *"there is also the **On the Way to a Smile** mini series"*

Comment: @Memor-X, :-) I thought that was only an expression

Comment: @Memor-X, I checked out what you said but it appears it's only an audiobook series, is it? or are there real episodes we could enjoy watching?

Comment: @bzal it may only have been [Denzel's Episode](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=11339) to be animated

Comment: On the way to a smile is basically a series of novellas.

Comment: @bzal to be exact, the OVA adaptation of Crisis Core is *Last Order: Final Fantasy VII*.

Comment: Advent Children(AC), Before Crisis(BC), Crisis Core(CC), Dirge of Cerberus(DC).Coincidence ?

Comment: Now all these comments made me even more confuser? So....... what should I see directly after FFVII.(I'm not into games so just movie suggestions please?)

Comment: @bzal Final Fantasy is a game series. The main part of the plot is in games, so you're going to have to play games if you want to experience the entire story. You didn't mention if you played the first FFVII game but Advent Children really exists to give closure for its ambiguous ending, and all these other spinoffs are just to clarify some plot points from the game or show fans what happened to their favorite character. If you just want to watch some fight scenes with no context, it doesn't matter what order you take these things in; to follow the plot, you have to play the original game.

Comment: @Torisuda is right. The main story of the series is all lumped into the games. The animes are just a really very small part of the whole story. If you just watch those, I am pretty sure the story won't make much of a sense. Though the action is really cool if you're into that. 
If you're not into old games, a remake of Final Fantasy VII is coming on the new consoles. It will still take quite some time though to release.